# Submit button has no action in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have 3 models in my project and no form is showing any action when the submit button is pressed after putting all the inputs of the form.

**forms.py**

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'thumbnail', 'body', 'status', 'is_subsriber', 'meta', 'author']
```

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 999, unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 999, unique = True)
    thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='article', format='JPEG', options={'quality': 60})
    body = CKEditor5Field(config_name='extends')
    meta = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = blogstatus, default = "DF")
    is_subsriber = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    published_on = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    modified_on = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
```

**views.py**

```
def article_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = BlogForm()
    return render(request, 'article/post-form.html', {"form":form})
```

**index.html**

```html
<form class="form" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form.as_p}}
                        <button type="submit">Publish</button>
                    </form>
```

This is just one model and its form. I've tried using action in the html form but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to [django-ckeditor5](https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor-5/) package that I've installed. This works well using the django admin but it doesn't work when used in forms.

Answer (score 1):

In your template your form is missing the action property. It should look like this:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{% url 'name of the url pattern to your view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above. I've tried using action in the template as well but it doesn't work

Comment: @Dhiman, just to clarify. The page is not even reloading when you press the submit button?

Comment: Yes. I doesn't do anything. Neither it reloads or redirects to another page even if I add redirects

Comment: @Dhiman, if is not even reloading the page then its default behavior is being prevented. Check in your browser dev tools if the console is showing any error; check that the button is inside the form (it seems to be in your code, but maybe it was a simplification of a more complex form and the button ended outside the form in an oversight); also check for a piece of javascript preventing the default behavior of the submit button.